# How to set BrowserMob with WebDriver?

Tags: java, webdriver, browsermob

I am trying to intercept the requests made by Webdriver using BrowserMobProxy.

But the below code is not working..It is not able to open the site google.com.

It says the "Internet Explorer cannot open the site"

```
    proxyServer = new ProxyServer(9101);
    proxyServer.start();

    proxyServer.setCaptureHeaders(true);
    proxyServer.setCaptureContent(true);

    proxyServer.addRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void process(BrowserMobHttpRequest request, Har har) {
            System.out.println("From Process method");
        }
    });

    seleniumProxy = proxy.seleniumProxy();

    seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:9101");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
    capabilities.setCapability("ie.setProxyByServer", true);

    File file = new File("C:\\path\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("www.google.com");
```

I get the below error when trying to access google.com from webdrviver

`From Process method
Nov 09, 2014 2:07:58 AM net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.util.Log info
INFO: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com when requesting http://www.google.com/`

Comment: What happens when you use the **actual** URL in the `get` method call? In other words, when you use `driver.get("http://www.google.com");`, what happens? The `get` method is specified only to work on full URLs (including the protocol scheme), and not just the address.

Comment: Jim, I tried your solution and it still fails. This happens only when i am on WiFi connection with vpn connected..Otherwise it works fine..Any idea on how to resolve this? I posted the same question here also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/browsermob-proxy/QRetOsrQFjk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsermob uses xbill DNS instead of regular Java/native DNS resolution, which may not play nice with your VPN. The latest browsermob snapshot allows you to enable native DNS fallback by setting the system property `bmp.allowNativeDnsFallback` to true:

```
System.setProperty("bmp.allowNativeDnsFallback", "true");
proxyServer = new ProxyServer(9101);
proxyServer.start();
```

You can get the latest snapshot at the [browsermob github page](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy).

Comment: Did that work for you? If not, you can create a new issue at the browsermob github page.